# Преобразование прямого кода в десятичный

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно преобразовать прямой код в десятичный?

Прямой код лежит в векторе:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> code;
```

Содержимое вектора: `0x90 0xa8 0x02`.
При этом `code[0]` - десятичная часть, а в `code[2]` и `code[1]` целая. Причем старший бит в `code[2]` обозначает знак числа.

Я реализовал так:

```
    // calculate
    int8_t pm = 1;
    if (result[2] & 1<<7){
        pm=-1;
        result[2] ^= 1<<7;
    }
    y = (result[2]*256 + result[1] + result[0]/256.0) * pm;
```

Результат правильный. Но как-то длинно и, мне кажется, неэффективно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно, можно поиздеваться и сделать так:

```
double dres(const vector<unsigned char>&result)
{
    struct Data
    {
        unsigned long i: 23;
        int sign : 1;
    };
    Data *d = (Data*)&result[0];
    return double(d->i)/256 *(d->sign ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Ну, принцип вы поняли?

У вас мне *очень* не нравится то, что вы меняете `result[2]`:

```
result[2] ^= 1<<7;
```

Comment: Для little-endian (например, x-86) правильно, а для big-endian нулевой и второй байты придется менять местами.

Comment: @Harry, разбираюсь в вашем коде. Я еще совсем новичок в С/C++, поэтому не очевидно. Но разберусь.